# Capacitor discharges in rectifier circuit

Tags: capacitor, rectifier

Is the diode that discharges the capacitor when it cut the current or the discharges of the capacitor that block the diode?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCwwX7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diode is blocked when Ve - Vc < Vth
Ve is the source:
Vc the capasitor,
Vth the threshold of the diode:
So the diode state neends on Vc, however Vc becomes greater than Ve because his voltage decreases less quickly, but his unload depends on the state of the diode.
Thank you

Comment: The diode does not discharge the capacitor in your circuit. I am unable to understand your language sufficiently to answer in more detail. Get google to translate your question from your natural tongue.

Comment: No, I mean when the diode bloc the current, is it in that moment that the capasitor wants to unload ?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: no, this is just a wondering

Comment: If you're "just wondering" is might be **very educational** to simulate this circuit, for example in Falstad: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/  or LTSpice.

Comment: Ok,Thank you, I have already using pspice.

Comment: @kodi. Good. Because with these **small RC values** you are probably causing more confusion for your understanding. The "discharge phase" is not actually the negative semi-cycle but the second half of the positive semi-cycle. Experiment with larger R and C values and see the circuit working as you expect (filtered half-wave rectifier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the power supply has completed its positive half-cycle, the capacitor is charged to its maximum voltage. While the power supply is in its negative half-cycle, the diode blocks current from flowing from the power supply. It is during this half-cycle that the capacitor discharges through the resistor. The time constant for discharge is RC = 68 usec, so in the discharge phase, the capacitor discharges essentially to zero volts.